# Код не грузит файлы

Tags: fileupload, upload, php

```
<?php

$uploadDir = '../../media/audio/'; //папка для хранения файлов

$allowedExt = array('mp3', 'm4a', 'wma', 'ra', 'mpa', 'mid', 'm3u', 'iff', 'aif', 'wav');
$maxFileSize = 20 * 1024 * 1024; //10 MB

//если получен файл
if (isset($_FILES)) {
    //проверяем размер и тип файла
    $ext = end(explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['Filedata']['name'])));
    if (!in_array($ext, $allowedExt)) {
        return;
    }
    if ($maxFileSize < $_FILES['Filedata']['size']) {
      echo 'Файл слишком большой';
    }
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'])) {
        $fileName = $uploadDir.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
        //если файл с таким именем уже существует...
        if (file_exists($fileName)) {
            //...добавляем текущее время к имени файла
            $nameParts = explode('.', $_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
            $nameParts[count($nameParts)-2] .= time();
            $fileName = $uploadDir.implode('.', $nameParts);
        }
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $fileName);

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: expode не будет возвращать разделитель, поэтому в $ext будет `mp3`, но никогда не будет `.mp3`.

Как никогда ваш капитан.

Comment: Спасибо вопрос решен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explode вернет значение без точки (обрежет по ней), а у вас в массиве расширения с точками. 
Поубирайте точки в массиве

Comment: Спасибо вопрос решен